# how to nest graphql queries

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

All the examples I find have a `query` top level object, then a list of queries, which then return types to go deeper.

Since I have a large number of queries, I would like to group them up, this is what I tried:

```
const AppType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'App',
    description: 'Generic App Details',

    fields: () => ({
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        appId: { type: GraphQLInt },
    }),
});

const MyFirstQuery = {
    type: new GraphQLList(AppType),
    args: {
        appId: { type: GraphQLInt },
    },
    resolve: (root, args) => fetchApp(args.appId),
};     

/* snip MySecondQuery, MyThirdQuery, MyFourthQuery */

const MyFirstGroupQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'myFirstGroup',
    description: 'the first group of queries',

    fields: () => ({
        myFirstQuery: MyFirstQuery,
        mySecondQuery: MySecondQuery,
        myThirdQuery: MyThirdQuery,
        myFourthQuery: MyFourthQuery,
    }),
});

/* snip MySecondGroupQuery, MyThirdGroupQuery and their types */    

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'query',
    description: 'read-only query',

    fields: () => ({
        myFirstGroup: MyFirstGroupQuery,
        mySecondGroup: MySecondGroupQuery,
        myThirdGroup: MyThirdGroupQuery,
    }),
});

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryType,
});
```

Why can't I make `MyFirstGroupQuery` like I did `QueryType` to make more nesting levels? The code works fine if I put all queries in `QueryType`, but my `MyFirstGroupQuery` produces errors:

```
Error: query.myFirstGroup field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.
```

How do I accomplish what I want? I really don't want to just prefix all my queries.

Comment: you mean like you declared the `Quertype` in `GraphQLSchema`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error `query.myFirstGroup field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.` means that you haven't provided the type for `myFirstGroup`
you have to provide the type using  `type` field

`myFirstGroup: {
            type: MyFirstGroupQuery,
            resolve: () => MyFirstGroupQuery,
        },`

and if the type `MyFirstGroupQuery` each field must have the `type` defined such as `GraphQLInt`, `GraphQLString`, `GraphQLID` even if it's tht customtype like `MyFirstGroupQuery`

In `GraphQLSchema` constructor function you provide your `RootQuery` which is `QueryType`, It's a `GraphQLSchema` it only accepts the `rootQuery` with the `GraphQLObjectType` whose fields must have the `type` defined

GraphQL is strictly type based, every field you declared must have the `type` defined

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/schema.js#L32

```
const {
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLList,
} = require('graphql');

const AppType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'App',
    description: 'Generic App Details',

    fields: () => ({
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        appId: { type: GraphQLInt },
    }),
});

// const MyFirstQuery = {
//     type: new GraphQLList(AppType),
//     args: {
//         appId: { type: GraphQLInt },
//     },
//     resolve: (root, args) => fetchApp(args.appId),
// };

const myFirstQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'First',
    fields: () => ({
        app: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AppType),
            args: {
                appId: { type: GraphQLInt },
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => fetchApp(args.appId),
        },
    }),
});

/* snip MySecondQuery, MyThirdQuery, MyFourthQuery */

const MyFirstGroupQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'myFirstGroup',
    description: 'the first group of queries',
    fields: () => ({
        myFirstQuery: {
            type: myFirstQuery,
            resolve: () => [], // promise
        },
        // mySecondQuery: {
        //     type: MySecondQuery,
        //     resolve: () => //data
        // }
        // myThirdQuery: {
        //     type: MyThirdQuery,
        //     resolve: () => // data
        // }
        // myFourthQuery: {
        //     type: MyFourthQuery,
        //     resolve: () => //data
        // }
    }),
});

/* snip MySecondGroupQuery, MyThirdGroupQuery and their types */

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'query',
    description: 'read-only query',

    fields: () => ({
        myFirstGroup: {
            type: MyFirstGroupQuery,
            resolve: () => MyFirstGroupQuery,
        },
        // mySecondGroup: {
        //     type: MySecondGroupQuery,
        //     resolve: MySecondGroupQuery
        // }
        // myThirdGroup: {
        //     type: MyThirdGroupQuery,
        //     resolve: MyThirdGroupQuery
        // }
    }),
});

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryType,
});

module.exports = Schema;
```

GraphiQL

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The fact the type was omitted from `GraphQLSchema` was what tripped me up!